# Не удается задать вопрос

Tags: поддержка, мета

Я на мете ни один вопрос задать не могу!!! Кол-во символов нормальное (я пробовал и без нижней строчки).

> [image: тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества]

Comment: Слишком мало символов, очевидно же.

Comment: 45, должно быть 50?

Comment: Если в вопросе мало символов, вставьте «Рыбу», например, Lorem Ipsum, → отправьте вопрос → удалите «рыбу».

Comment: спасибо, прикольно

Comment: Касательно самого вопроса, нажмите в верхнем меню на кнопку, где Ваша репутация (**http://i.imgur.com/WYHZIJi.png**) → далее нажимаете на «Вопросы» (**http://i.imgur.com/9qDTeO2.png**) → увидите все свои заданные вопросы. Спасибо.

Comment: Все равно не получается задать вопрос, пусть кто-нибудь попробует и вышлет скрин.

Comment: Я текст уже добавлял

Comment: Аллелуя, с 1000 попытки получилось http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4053/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: [Ознакомьтесь](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3392/176217) с вариантами.