# Проблема с метками для перенесенных вопросов

Tags: дефект, синонимы-меток, перенос-вопросов

Для перенесенного с основного сайта на Мету [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4052/176217) почему-то отображается метка-синоним [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), а не основная [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5):

> [image: скрин вопроса]

По [списку ревизий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/588750/revisions) вообще не очень понятно в какой момент она появилась у вопроса.

При этом любопытно заметить, что, вероятно, перенос вопроса привёл к [созданию метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new):

> [image: новые метки]

Comment: Да, она сразу добавляется по умолчанию. Думаю, это норма )

Comment: @NickVolynkin видимо из-за требования хотя бы одной необходимой. Но странно, что не подменяется основной. Наверное, захардкожено.

Comment: как и многое тут)